# Display frame rate during playback

Tags: video-sequence-editor

During playback of a video file, my configuration (2.72 on Windows 7) does not show the frame rate in the upper right corner of the Video Sequence Editor's Image Preview window.  How can I turn it on?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to *User Preferences* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and check the ***Playback FPS*** box in the *Interface* header.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, as well for the short-cut; the best I could do before was File->U.